# Magento2 cron job fails

Tags: magento2, cron

My update cron job is failing. The cron entry is:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
```

and the error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')' in /var/www/magento2/update/app/code/Magento/Update/UpdateLoggerFactory.php on line 31
```

Line 31 from UpdateLoggerFactory.php:

```
 $logFile = MAGENTO_BP . '/var/log/update.log',
```

belonging to the block:

```
public function __construct(
    $logFile = MAGENTO_BP . '/var/log/update.log',
    $channelName = 'update-cron'
) {
```

I am using Ubuntu Server 14.04, php 5.5.9, Apache 2.4.7

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP **5.6** introduces concatenation in function argument declarations. See example [on 5.5](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85ca0554572545c9f168ef3b699af5befb45d366) vs [on 5.6](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85ca0554572545c9f168ef3b699af5befb45d366).

I'm currently failing to find a reference for this change in the PHP documentation, but will edit when I do.

Which version of M2 are you using? I can't find that file on the GitHub repository. Possibly you're using an old M2 version, and [this is the new file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Cron/SetupLoggerFactory.php)?

If you do find the source file, the best way to fix it would be to submit a pull request to them to make it backwards compatible, i.e.:

```
public function __construct(
    $logFile = null,
    $channelName = 'update-cron'
) {
    if (is_null($logFile)) {
        $logFile = MAGENTO_BP . '/var/log/update.log';
    }
```

Comment: I installed using Composer, it is 2.0.7